# Stored procedure to distribute sales profit in hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a store procedure to distribute sales profit among the `UserID` in a given hierarchy above the user who does a sale

This is the code which i had written

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @SaleDistribution TABLE 
(
PackID      INT NULL,
SalesUserID         VARCHAR(10) NULL,
RowLevel            smallint NULL,
Createdon           Datetime NULL,
ActualPercentage    Decimal(18,5) NULL,
RelevantPercentage  Decimal(18,5) NULL,
Commision           Decimal(18,5) NULL,
PackRate    Decimal(18,5) NULL,
PreviousBalance     Decimal(18,5) NULL,
ParentID            VARCHAR(10) NULL,
IsActive            bit NULL,
IsBalanceUpdate     bit NULL,
ExtraPackAmount Decimal(18,5) NULL
)   

DECLARE @PackID VARCHAR(10) = '886',
    @PackRate DECIMAL(18,2)
SELECT @PackRate = PM.Price FROM UserPack US INNER JOIN PackageMaster PM ON US.PackageID=PM.PackageID where US.PackID= @PackID

DECLARE @RowNum INT = 1 
DECLARE @id BIGINT
DECLARE @Count  INT 
SET @id = 118

;WITH tblParent AS
(
SELECT id, userid, assignto FROM UserMaster WHERE Id = @id
UNION ALL
SELECT um.id, um.userid, um.assignto FROM Usermaster  um JOIN tblParent  ON um.userId = tblParent.assignto
)

SELECT userid, assignto into #temp FROM tblParent order by assignto asc
Set @Count = (Select Count(UserID) from #temp)

while @RowNum <= @Count
BEGIN

Insert into @SaleDistribution (PackID,SalesUserID,RowLevel,Createdon,ActualPercentage, PackRate,PreviousBalance, ParentID, ExtraPackAmount)
SELECT @PackID as PackID, temp.UserID as SalesUserID, @RowNum as RowLevel, Getdate() as CreatedOn,
ISnULL(tcm.Commision,'0.0000'),
@PackRate as PackRate,
SAM.Balance as PreviousBalance, AssignTo as ParentID, (us.PaymentAmount - @PackRate) as ExtraPackAmount  from
(SELECT userid,  Assignto, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY assignto asc) RowNum FROM #temp)temp Left Join SalesAccountbalance SAM ON SAM.UseriD = temp.UserID 
Left join CommMaster tcm on tcm.userid = temp.userid
LEFT JOIN Packtransaction st on st.salesuserid = @id 
LEFT JOIN UserPack us on us.PackID = @PackID and st.salesuserid = @id
WHERE RowNum = @RowNum
group by tcm.Commision,temp.userid, SAM.Balance, temp.Assignto,us.PaymentAmount,temp.RowNum

SET @RowNum = @RowNum + 1
END
select * from @SaleDistribution
Drop table #temp
END
```

The output what i am expecting is as below

```
PackID  SalesUserID     RowLevel    Createdon               ActualPercentage    RelevantPercentage  Commision   SubscriptionRate    PreviousBalance ParentID    IsActive    IsBalanceUpdate ExtraPackageAmount
886     1               1           2015-11-09 14:17:04.260 0.00000             50.00000            17500.0000  35000.00000         -4998.50000     0           NULL        NULL            NULL
886     22              2           2015-11-09 14:17:04.260 0.00000             0.0000              0.0000      35000.00000         -2000.00000     1           NULL        NULL            NULL
886     24              3           2015-11-09 14:17:04.260 0.00000             0.0000              0.0000      35000.00000         NULL            22          NULL        NULL            NULL
886     118             4           2015-11-09 14:17:04.260 50.00000            50.0000             17500.0000  35000.00000         -1450.00000     24          NULL        NULL            NULL
```

But the Output i am getting is as below

```
PackID  SalesUserID     RowLevel    Createdon               ActualPercentage    RelevantPercentage  Commision   SubscriptionRate    PreviousBalance ParentID    IsActive    IsBalanceUpdate ExtraPackageAmount
886     1               1           2015-11-09 14:17:04.260 0.00000             NULL                NULL        35000.00000         -4998.50000     0           NULL        NULL            NULL
886     22              2           2015-11-09 14:17:04.260 0.00000             NULL                NULL        35000.00000         -2000.00000     1           NULL        NULL            NULL
886     24              3           2015-11-09 14:17:04.260 0.00000             NULL                NULL        35000.00000         NULL            22          NULL        NULL            NULL
886     118             4           2015-11-09 14:17:04.260 50.00000            NULL                NULL        35000.00000         -1450.00000     24          NULL        NULL            NULL
```

Kindly guide where am i going wrong

Comment: 1. Your sp will throw an error on the insert statement because you are referring to a column "calc" which is not present in the temp table variable. 2. You are taking ISnULL(tcm.Commision,'0.0000') as Actual Percentage and 100 - ISnULL(tcm.Commision,'0.0000') as RelevantPercentage. Why do expect RelevantPercentage to be 50 in your first row in the expected output table?

Comment: because i am finally going to count what is the exact amount in percentage that will be distributed so that is why kept that `RelevantPercentage` column. also kindly see for the updates in question

Comment: The output does not match the `@SaleDistribution`, please fix that first.  ie `@SaleDistribution` has 9 columns, but your resultset has 13.

Comment: Because the insert is made on few specific columns and in the end there is a statement which looks something like this `select * from @SaleDistribution` that is the reason the output resultset show `13 columns` instead of `9 columns`. please go through the code first atleast for your reference.

Comment: can you clarify exactly what the issue is?  Is the issue, you cannot figure out how or where to calculate RelevantPercentage and Commission?  That is the only difference i see in the resultset, and there is no reference to those two columns outside of the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think your insert query is wrong. Please check these Columns "calc, cOMMISION"

```
Insert into @SaleDistribution (PackID,SalesUserID,RowLevel,Createdon,ActualPercentage,**calc, cOMMISION**, PackRate,PreviousBalance, ParentID, ExtraPackAmount)
```

Comment: That calc and cOmmision was for testing purpose, just wanted to know where am i going wrong in distributing and getting output as expected

Comment: Please further remove unnecessary/debugging info from the repo, so we don't spend time looking at the non-relevant info.